# "npm install" is not downloading all files from the "babel-core" package, but it does if I specifically install "babel-core". Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

This is my [package.json](https://github.com/gearz-lab/gearz/blob/master/package.json).

If I do an `npm install` from the root folder, it installs all the packages. However, the `./node_modules/babel-core/` folder will only have these files:

- browser.min.js
- browser-polyfill.js
- package.json

[image: img]

Some files are missing, like the `register.js` file.

However, if I manually install `babel-core`, like this: `npm install babel-core`, the `./node_modules/babel-core/` folder will be complete. The `register.js` file will not be missing.

[image: img]

What I don't understand is: How can some files be missing if I install all the packages but not be missing if I install a specific package?

OBS: I'm having this problem running on a `Ubuntu` VM. Node version: 0.12.X. This problem seems not to occur when I'm on Windows.

Comment: Do you have anything custom about your npm configuration? That seems really weird.

Comment: Looking at https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-core, on its own, outside of the babel module, what is babel-core even supposed to be? Just install babel, and let that resolve its own local dependencies?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `babel-core` is the API module, many things use it and you can use it to manually transform files. Most build tool integrations use it. If you don't need the CLI scripts, there is no reason to install `babel`.